# Query to copy field data to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Got a problem where a column in one table that due to an error has been blank for ages, but the data for that column exists in a different table.  This data is specific to users, and the users may exist in multiple iterations in the table with missing data.

Ultimately my query so far looks like this:

```
UPDATE reviews SET reviews.signature = (SELECT users.singature FROM users WHERE users.id = ???) WHERE reviews.userid = ???
```

the `???` areas are where I'm having issues..

is this even possible? Im going to guess my query is totally wrong, but im open to try any suggestions

Comment: Are the 2 tables related?Is there a common field?

Comment: yup they're in the same db, each review has the userid field and a signature field. The users table has a signature field which contains the current signature. But the signature hasn't been copied in hundreds and hundreds of review records, so Im trying to find a query that copies the contents of the review users signature and set the reviews signature to that

Comment: Same db yes,can can you join them.A column which is identical in both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `JOIN` between the tables like

```
UPDATE reviews a 
    JOIN users b ON a.userid = b.id       
    SET a.signature = b.signature
```

Comment: I had no idea a JOIN was valid for an update, I will try this out

Comment: YOUR A LIFE SAVER. THANK YOU!

Comment: I was trying to, but had to wait a threshold amount of time in order to do it lol